# Determine which element comes first

Tags: jquery

I have an array with objects id's:

```
one
two
there
etc..
```

And i have quite a long object list:

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="one" />
  <input type="text" id="two" />
  <input type="text" id="three" />
</div>
```

This is not the actual html code, just a simplified version.

Now my array with id's keeps changing, and my question would be
how can i find out which element from that array is the first element in `#container` div

For example if i have this order:

```
{
  email 
  name
  date
}
```

And this list of html objects

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="text" id="last_name" />
  <input type="text" id="email" />
  <input type="text" id="date" />
</div>
```

`name` would be first, but in that array in some cases `name` item won't exist so it won't always be the name, i hope this makes any sense :)

Comment: sorry I edited your post but the inpu/input typo was reaaaally bothering me.

Comment: I don't think he merely wants to select the first element. The question says he wants to find the first element that is also represented in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sync your array order with the document order, you could do this:

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="text" id="last_name" />
  <input type="text" id="email" />
  <input type="text" id="date" />
</div>​
```

JS:

```
var arr = ["email", "name", "date"];
var elems = $("#" + arr.join(", #") );


arr = $.map($.unique(elems.get()), function(v,i) {
    return v.id;
});

console.log(arr);
//["name", "email", "date"] ​​​​​​ same order as they are in the document
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKz9U/1/

The [`$.unique`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) sorts the elements to the same order as they are in the document

Answer (score 2):

This will loop through the elements, first to last and show you the ID of each.

```
$('#container input').each(function() {
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

`$('#container input').eq(0)` will also refer to the first input element.

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstId = $("#container").first().attr("id");
```

I think this code is incorrect.  Perhaps this instead:

```
var firstId = $("#container").children().first().attr("id");
```